# PowerShell List all build errors while building the solution using devenv

Tags: powershell-4.0, devenv

Hi all I have written a PowerShell which will build the solution using `devenv` from PowerShell. Everything is working fine but what ever the errors I am getting while building from Visual Studio those errors I am unable to see in the log file, the only thing I am getting as

`========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

But not the actual errors, here is the script

```
$vsPath= (Get-Item  'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe').GetValue($name)
$parameters = """$SlnFile"" /Build development /project ""$SlnPath"" /out $logPath"
Start-Process -FilePath $vsPath -ArgumentList $parameters -Wait
```

Comment: Instead of `""` use escaping via backtick: ```$parameters = "`"$SlnFile`" /Build development /project `"$SlnPath`" /out `"$logPath`""```

Comment: Tried but I am not seeing the errors as the same is Visual Studio, the same line I am seeing `========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: VS creates a debug log somewhere in the project folder. You can also set its console verbosity level to debug in Options - Projects - Build

Comment: Hi the log file is getting created but the problem is the errors that are showing up while opening up the same solution and build it using visual studio